# Landscape xib for ipad version only

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xib, landscape

I have a universal app with seperate xibs for iPhone and iPad

For the iPad version, I want my one of my iPad xibs in landscape mode.  I have set it to landscape in simulated metrics, (The app is set for portrait in the summary screen) and the landscape view still shows in portrait when run.  Im sure I read on here a naming convention that tells the app the xib is in landscape ie: `view1_one.xib~ipad-landscape`

Ive tried using screen rotation methods but iOS 6 screen rotation is just proving so frustrating as I have tried so many solutions all of which have no effect.  I have done screen rotation before in iOS 6 but I was using storyboards and subclassed a navigation controller for my chosen view, I dont know how to do this with this code as I picked it ip from someone else

So to sum up: How can I get my screen to respect  the landscape xib I have created in interface builder instead of showing it in portrait

I would point out I have searched on here for a solution and spent many hours on this before posting this

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem without any code and settings. Can you upload sample code and I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are naming conventions for resources (including xib's) that specify on which device type they are loaded. However, these do not exist for specific orientations. `-landscape` won't do anything extra (more specifically, it will probably load the resource on an iPhone as well, which isn't what you want).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW2

As for handling orientation changes, make sure you implement both the iOS 5 and below methods and the iOS 6 methods for handling them:

```
// Older versions of iOS (deprecated)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

// iOS6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

// iOS6
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

// Added after comment
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

This is the official way to ensure that your viewController is only loaded in landscape.

**Edit:**

I added the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` method as well. While personally I don't like this method, it forces the viewController to present in that orientation, until the next orientation change. Not nice, but it will help you to see if your orientation methods get called at all.

Also try to set a breakpoint in each of these methods. If they don't get called at all, your issue might be with the subclassing. Be certain that the viewController in the storyboard is set to the subclass and not the superclass.

**Edit2:**

Check this in Interface Builder:

[image: Make sure that the ViewController in Interface Builder is set to the appropriate subclass]

Comment: Thanks for answer, and the info about naming conventions, ive tried th e above code you posted very early on in my quest.  It has absolutely no effect.  Its what I use in storyboards but I have to subclass a view controller for the screens I want to rotate to override the global settings. Im not sure how to do that with the code I have.

Comment: Thanks for update, still nothing, Im not actually using storyboards im using xibs, i was just saying if i was using storyboards id have this sorted by subclassing a navigation controller.  This iOS 6 rotation is just so frustrating. Tried breakpoints, nothing happens.  One screen...So much hassle!

Comment: 'Nothing happens' is rather important. If the debugger doesn't break in these methods, this means that they're not being called at all. You said that you 'have to subclass' to override general settings. In your xib, what class is set when you select the ViewController? That should be set to the subclass.

Comment: No I haven't subclassed anything, sorry I've confused matters mentioning that at all, NORMALLY thats what I would do.  In this Instance I have picked up some code from another dev i just cant chang e any screens rotation from the global settings. thanks anyway, plus one for your help

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question. It's good for people to know what the final solution was.

Comment: Hi Spacey that would be great if I had a final solution.  Still trying to get this to work

Comment: There is no final solution. Beyond subclassing, there is no way to change how a certain views respond to orientation changes. Since you came up with that on your own, you can answer your own question.